# Internal Server Error when file or folder does not exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internal-server-error

I use this rewrite code to rewrite all requests to `.php` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

So when I enter `index` the `index.php` will load  or if I enter `contact` the `contact.php` will load.

But when I enter a name which does not exists I will get Internal Server Error, for example I entered this name `test` or `fdgdfg/ewrtt/ddfghdfg`, after this I will get this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mydomain.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I have `ErrorDocument 404 error.php` too in my `.htaccess`.

this is my complete `.htaccess` file :

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /shop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Are you sure u get internal server error and not a infinite redirect loop message? try with another browser just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the php file actually exists, otherwise the 2 conditions that you have will always fail and the `.php` extension keeps getting appended, e.g. you'd end up with a URI looking like:

```
/shop/foo.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
```

until the internal recursion limit is reached and you get a 500 error. Try adding another condition to check if the file exists:

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /shop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following solved my problem -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```